# Hide first <li> element

Tags: css, css-selectors

My HTML structure is as per the following:

```
<nav class="main-nav">
<ul>
  <li class="gallery-collection">
    <a href="/">Welcome</a>          <!-- Hide this -->
  </li>
  <li class="page-collection">
    <a href="/about/">About</a>
  </li>
  <li class="gallery-collection">
    <a href="/support/">Support</a>
  </li>
  ...
```

How do I hide the first element saying "Welcome" using CSS? Note that 2 elements have the same class here: 'gallery-collection'.

Comment: If your question has been answered, please accept an answer to close off this question

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Max compatibility:

```
.main-nav li {
    display: none;
}
.main-nav li + li {
    display: list-item;
}
```

Less compatibility, but not too bad:

```
.main-nav ul li:first-child {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: I like the `li + li` trick :). For those wondering, the "less compatible" (ie. `first-child`) version do not work in IE6 and earlier and is quirky in IE7 and IE8 (http://www.quirksmode.org/css/selectors/)

Comment: @GuillaumeAlgis Yea, the first-child method should work fine for most use cases, the above is the cleanest fully compatible version though. It is indeed a cool trick, also useful for things like 3rd column and onwards in a table `tr td + td + td {` (If can't use nth-child)

Comment: In terms of browser compatibility there is virtually no benefit of using `+` over `:first-child` other than to work around a bug that you won't even encounter 99% of the time. But I guess better safe than sorry, right?

Comment: @SmokeyPHP: Sorry, both of the versions did not work for me. Here is my website: playgigit.squarespace.com

Comment: @BoltClock I'll assume that's a joke.. if not let me inform you that `+` is supported ~3 IE versions further back than `first-child`. As I already mentioned above, `first-child` should be enough most of the time, but `+` is definitely more widely compatible

Comment: @rdesai The styles are being overridden by `#topNav .main-nav ul li` selector. You can just add `#topNav ` in front of my selector to stop the overriding

Comment: @SmokeyPHP: `:first-child` is supported by IE7 and IE8 barring the edge case that's been mentioned. I don't think `+` is supported all the way back to IE4, if that's the ~3 IE versions you're referring to.

Comment: @BoltClock I'd barely say IE7 has proper support of first-child! Anyway... did changing the selector sort it for you rdesai ?

Answer (score 4):

With CSS only (as your question was only tagged `css`):

```
.main-nav li:first-of-type
{
    display:none;
}
```

The `:first-of-type` selector is supported in all major browsers, except IE8 and earlier.

Comment: IE8 supports first-child though, which would be beneficial in this situation unless I'm mistaken. So nav.main-nav ul li:first-child {}

Comment: @OkamiStudio Indeed - for the most compatible ways of achieving this, see my answer

Comment: @OkamiStudio you're right. Too be fair, the question is overly broad.

Comment: Also when it comes to `li` elements, assuming proper markup it's safe to use `:first-child` over `:first-of-type` to gain that extra browser support, since `li` elements shouldn't have siblings of any other type.